# Lottery with Supernumber

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, random, constants

I came across the challenge of building a random numbers generator for the lottery.
6 numbers, which are between 1 and 49, none of which appears to be twice, in ascending order. One 7th number, the super-seven, not sorted, can't be one of the previous numbers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const numb = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        numb[i] = Math.floor(49 * Math.random()) + 1;

        //compare to existing numbs
        for (var k = 0; k < numb.length - 1; k++) {
            if (numb[i] == numb[k]) {
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    let supNumb = new Array();
    supNumb = Math.floor(49 * Math.random()) + 1;
    for (var s = 0; s <= 1; s++) {
        // compare supNumb to numb
        for (var t = 0; t < numb.length - 1; t++) {
            if (supNumb == numb[t]) {
                s--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    // SORT & DISPLAY NUMBERS 
    function sort(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    numb.sort(sort);
    document.write("<p> " + numb);
    document.write("<h4>" + "SuperSeven: " + supNumb);
</script>
```

I know by trying the super-seven `supNumb` is still giving out same numbers as in `numb`.
I can't get it to work and can't find anywhere this being mentioned.

Somebody here can look over it and let me know how I can compare `supNumb` to `numb`?

Is this even the right structure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to be consistent. If you are using `const`, use also the rest of the ES6 features (`let`, arrow functions, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an infinit loop and break it if you find a valid number like so:

```
while(true){
    supNumb = Math.floor(49 * Math.random()) + 1;
    if(numb.indexOf(supNumb) < 0){
        break;
    }
}
```

Also better use `indexOf` so search in the array. It is much faster than plain JS.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

---

You could even use the `Set` mechanics to achieve this. Sets can only store unique values. All duplicates will thereby be ignored:

```
var numbers = new Set(),
    supNumb = 0;
while(numbers.size < 6){
    numbers.add(Math.floor(49 * Math.random()) + 1);
}
while(true){
    supNumb = Math.floor(49 * Math.random()) + 1;
    if(!numbers.has(supNumb)) break;
}
var sortedNumbers = [...numbers].sort((a,b)=>{return a-b})
console.log(sortedNumbers, supNumb);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0):

You have supNumb as an Array, I think it should be a scalar (single integer) as you are doing a compare against array member of your array numb

As well you'd have to regenerate via Random if the supNumb fails to pass he criteria 'it must be unique'

Answer (score 0):

To sample non-repeating numbers there is a method called [Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It is guaranteed to select 7 non-repeating numbers from 1...49 range, without any secondary checks.

In some pseudocode (sorry, don't know Javascript)

```
a = _.range(1, 50);

for i from n−1 downto 1 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
     exchange a[j] and a[i]

sort(a, 6); // sort first 6 elements
super = a[6];
```